# Trying to send email from nagios

Tags: amazon-ec2, nagios

I'm very new to Nagios. I'm trying to send email alerts. But that doesn't seem to be working.

But in my log of nagios I can see this :

```
SERVICE ALERT: Appserver;Tmp directory;CRITICAL;HARD;1;
```

Where host notifications are generated via email, only service alerts are not working. And when I look at `sendEmail` log I can see this :

```
Sep 14 12:38:39 x.x.x.x. sendEmail[23005]: ERROR => You must specify a 'from' field!  Try --help.
Sep 14 12:39:39 x.x.x.x.x. sendEmail[23129]: ERROR => You must specify a 'from' field!  Try --help.
Sep 14 12:40:39 x-x-x-x-x sendEmail[23233]: ERROR => You must specify a 'from' field!  Try --help.
```

Where I'm making the mistake?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify which distro you were using on your EC2 instance, but the notify-host-by-email command definition that's on my Ubuntu Lucid box looks like:

```
define command{
    command_name    notify-host-by-email
    command_line    /usr/bin/printf "%b" "***** Nagios *****\n\nNotification Type: $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$\nHost: $HOSTNAME$\nState: $HOSTSTATE$\nAddress: $HOSTADDRESS$\nInfo: $HOSTOUTPUT$\n\nDate/Time: $LONGDATETIME$\n" | /usr/bin/mail -s "$HOSTSTATE$ - $HOSTNAME$ ping"  -r "Nagios Alert <systems@example.com>" $CONTACTEMAIL$
    }
```

and the notify-service-by-email looks like:

```
define command{
    command_name    notify-service-by-email
    command_line    /usr/bin/printf "%b" "***** Nagios *****\n\nNotification Type: $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$\n\nService: $SERVICEDESC$\nHost: $HOSTALIAS$\nAddress: $HOSTADDRESS$\nState: $SERVICESTATE$\n\nDate/Time: $LONGDATETIME$\n\nAdditional Info:\n\n$SERVICEOUTPUT$" | /usr/bin/mail -s "$SERVICESTATE$ $HOSTALIAS$/$SERVICEDESC$"  -r "Nagios Alert <systems@example.com>" $CONTACTEMAIL$
    }
```

So, what Nagios basically does is pipe the formatted message body to the `/usr/bin/mail` command, which has a bunch of command line options to specify the Subject, the Reply-to, etc.  In particular, I'm explicitly setting the From: with the "-r" option because I want such notifications to come from our general "systems" mailing list.

You may have set up your own notify-by-email command.  Look at the man page for your system `mail` command to see what options you can use to specify the usual mail headers.

Answer (score 0):

You have to look for the command definition that is used to send out notifications. In my case all my notification commands are in *nagios/etc/misccommands.cfg*. Somewhere in that definition is the command that is run to send out notification e-mails. You have to fix that. I am a Solaris guy and not familiar with the *sendEmail* command but the man page should give you clues. Maybe compare the host notification definition with the service notification definition and look for differences.